# When using a command in a command subgroup, it always lose every options

Tags: python, discord, pycord

I was designing a Discord bot that supports slash commands. Then, I created a command in "subgroup" with 4 options. However, when I ran the bot, the command appeared in Discord, but **all the options were lost**.

This is my code:

```
user_info = bot.create_group(name="user_info", description="使用者的資訊、經驗值等。")
edit = user_info.create_subgroup(name="edit", description="編輯使用者的資訊。")

@edit.command(name="exp", description="編輯使用者的經驗值。")
async def exp(ctx,
              使用者: Option(discord.Member, "要編輯的使用者", required=True),
              類型: Option(str, "要編輯的經驗值類型", required=True, choices=["text", "voice"]),
              經驗值: Option(int, "要編輯的經驗值數量，若要扣除則輸入負值", required=True),
              私人訊息: Option(bool, "是否以私人訊息回應", required=False) = False):
    if ctx.author == bot.get_user(657519721138094080):
        before_exp = user_exp.get_exp(使用者.id, 類型)
        user_exp.add_exp(使用者.id, 類型, 經驗值)
        after_exp = user_exp.get_exp(使用者.id, 類型)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="編輯經驗值", description=f"已編輯{使用者.mention}的**{類型}**經驗值。",
                              color=default_color)
        embed.add_field(name="編輯前", value=before_exp, inline=True)
        if 經驗值 > 0:
            embed.add_field(name="➡️增加", value=f"*{經驗值}*", inline=True)
        else:
            embed.add_field(name="減少", value=f"*{abs(經驗值)}*", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="編輯後", value=after_exp, inline=True)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, ephemeral=私人訊息)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(title="錯誤", description="你沒有權限使用這個指令。", color=error_color)
        await ctx.respond(embed=embed, ephemeral=私人訊息)
```

As you can see, this command should have 4 options, but in Discord it was:
[image: The command lost all options]

All the options were gone! Did I use the wrong method?

Comment: You seem to have added `=False` after the last parameter in the `exp` function. This may be causing the error. Also, I believe the first line should be `SlashCommandGroup` instead of `bot.create_group`